# BadMethodCallException Method orderBy does not exist

Tags: php, database, orm

**Model**

```
<?php

class CommentComentario extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

    protected $table = 'comment_comentario';

    public function comercio() {
        return $this->belongsTo('CommentComercio', 'comercio_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Request**

```
$comercios = CommentComercio::all()->orderBy('created_at');
```

> **Error is produced in** illuminate\support\Traits\Macroable.php line 81

**Instalation composer**

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*",
        "slim/extras": "*",
        "illuminate/console": "*",
        "illuminate/database": "*",
        "illuminate/events": "*",
        "illuminate/filesystem": "*",
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "*",
        "monolog/monolog": "1.*",
        "twig/twig": "*",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [ "models" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: It is best if you restate your doubt as a question in the body of your post.  This will help people pinpoint what you need.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. did you get past this?

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
$comercios = CommentComercio::all()->orderBy('created_at');
```

To this:

```
$comercios = CommentComercio::orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

This will get "all" your items still, but have the order applied to it.